# Problem with Xposed 3.5.9 on alcatel idol 2 mini 6016d

Tags: applications

i had a problem with xposed framework i install it on my alcatel 6016d but when i install module , restart the phone don't boot ,stands on alcatel logo .

the only Solution this problem is power + up to format aphone.

i try xposed more than 27 times but no solution

i belive th problem is xposed don't support alcatel rom.

I wish to run Xposed on my phone with no problem 
Thanks.